# Can I use a context value as a click.option() default?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I want to use a value in my configuration (which I load into my context) as the default value for a click command option. I've read [this section](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#dynamic-defaults-for-prompts) of the documentation, and I don't think I'm understanding what I need do.

This is my example script:

```
import sys
import click

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    """
    CLI
    """
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)
    ctx.obj['DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT'] = "dev"


@cli.command()
@click.option('-e', '--environment', required=True, default=click.get_current_context().obj['DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT'])
def show_env(environment):
    click.echo(environment)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

The goal, if I run `python cli.py show-env`, is to get it to output `dev` (because I didn't pass the parameter as it's loaded from context).

This fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcli.py", line 15, in <module>
    @click.option('-e', '--environment', required=True, default=click.get_current_context().obj['DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT'])
  File "/home/devuser/.virtualenvs/cli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/globals.py", line 26, in get_current_context
    raise RuntimeError('There is no active click context.')
RuntimeError: There is no active click context.
```

I have also tried by using `@pass_context` on my `show_env` command like so:

```
@cli.command()
@click.option('-e', '--environment', required=True, default=ctx.obj['DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT'])
@click.pass_context
def show_env(ctx, environment):
    click.echo(environment)
```

Which fails because `ctx` isn't defined at that point.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcli.py", line 15, in <module>
    @click.option('-e', '--environment', required=True, default=ctx.obj['DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT'])
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

Am I able to use my context to set a command option default value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, the context does not yet exist at the time you are trying to examine it. You can delay the default lookup from context until the context does exist, by using a custom class like:

#### Custom Class

```
def default_from_context(default_name):

    class OptionDefaultFromContext(click.Option):

        def get_default(self, ctx):
            self.default = ctx.obj[default_name]
            return super(OptionDefaultFromContext, self).get_default(ctx)

    return OptionDefaultFromContext
```

#### Using the Custom Class

To use the custom class pass it to `click.option` via the `cls` parameter like:

```
@click.option('-e', '--environment', required=True,
              cls=default_from_context('DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT'))
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.option()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Option` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Option` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case, we override `click.Option.get_default()`.  In our `get_default()` we examine the context and set the default value.  We then call the parent `get_default()` to continue further processing.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    """
    CLI
    """
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)
    ctx.obj['DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT'] = "dev"


@cli.command()
@click.option('-e', '--environment', required=True,
              cls=default_from_context('DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT'))
def show_env(environment):
    click.echo(environment)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'show_env',
        '--help',
    )

    import sys, time
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
-----------
> show_env
dev
-----------
> --help
Usage: click_prog.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  CLI

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  show_env
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Stephen Rauch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043912) above, for Click 8, the signature of `click.Option.get_default` is `get_default(self, ctx: Context, call: bool = True)`, so you might need to add the `call` argument.